# Linux Mint 15 - Recieving DKPG error 127 when modifying packages

Tags: linux, linux-mint

```
*After this operation, 44.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Setting up install-info (4.13a.dfsg.1-10ubuntu4) ...
/etc/environment: line 5: JAVA_HOME: command not found
dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)*
```

This is the error I am running into whenever I try to modify any packages, in this case I was trying to install LXDE. My environment file looks like this :

```
*PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/
```

To give more context, this DKPG error began happening after I went through a long and arduous process setting up Android Studio. I feel like the solution is simple, but I have been searching for a while now and haven't been able to resolve my issue. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export your JAVA_HOME before executing the command

```
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/
```

Comment: You mean in the terminal or in the environment file ? Is this something I would have to do every time I modify packages? Thanks

Comment: You can try it first in your shell or add this to your .profile/.bashrc